# Is it normal for a laptop to discharge to 60% when not plugged in and not turned on for 5 days?

Tags: battery, lenovo-laptop, battery-life

I recently purchased a Lenovo IdeaPad Y400 and have noticed that after I do the following:

1. Use the laptop while plugged in
2. Shut down and unplug (it is fully charged at this point)
3. Turn it back on after a couple of days (between 5-6) - the battery indicator tells me that it is now around 60%

I realise that all batteries discharges even when not used but ~40% in less then a week seems a little excessive to me. Is this normal behaviour?

Note that the usual things like LAN wake-up and always-on USB are all turned off in BIOS/don't exist.

Comment: Not terribly abnormal.

Comment: Are you sure the system was really shut-down and not in one of the new Connected-Standby-modes introduced with Windows 8?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same laptop, Its actually a feature on the laptop that will extend the life of the battery. Because a full charge will decrease it. In order to change it to a full charge, you have to Energy Management program and select the Maximum Battery life instead of the Optimized battery health option.

Answer (score 2):

It has do with lenovo Energy Management.It prolongs your battery life as lenovo suggets(charges upto 60%). You can search for the software which manages its called "Energy Management" itself.
To change the settings so that you can use the device it for long time ,go to energy management software and select(check mark) Maximum battery life(charges to 100%).
Have FUN!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem *that* strange, although maybe a little faster than I'd expect. You can try and confirm that nothing on the computer is improperly drawing power by taking the battery out and letting it sit for the 5-6 days, then putting it back in and seeing what the level is at.

Comment: Though it should be noted that there will be a slight drain on the battery when off, simply due to the power switch logic and the real time clock, if nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

I checked with my local Lenovo rep and it appears that this is a feature of some new Lenovo laptops where machines which are left alone for extended periods (i.e. days in my case) would discharged to around 60% automatically to extend battery life. It is possible to turn this off; I will do this to see if it is indeed doing whatever Lenovo is telling me.

Answer (score 0):

A battery should not discharge that fast just due to the chemical self discharge. If it is in standby then it is normal. The discharge from RTC and other thing that means that the computer is not completely off will not draw that much.

It is true that Li-ion batteries will survive longer at around 60% than at full charge, I personally would not want it to do that by itself after just a few days, the battery does have a limited number of discharge cycles after all.